# PHP - Check for a match of 2 words in a string that appear within a certain distance of each other

Tags: php, string

I've had a good look around and I'm still not really sure what kind of function that can do this.

If I have a string like

```
$str = 'These people came from some area in France';
```

And these 2 words which occur in the above string.

```
$match1 = 'from'; $match2 = 'France';
```

How can I check that the two words are within 20 characters of each other?

Comment: Try a regular expression, I think that would do it.

Comment: Got an example? :) I really need to learn a bit of reg ex!

Comment: Something as simple as `/from.{1,20}France/` might work, just test whether the string matches that.

Comment: @Nick, Rocket's example above is what I had in mind. That said, consider answers here sometimes as clues to aid you in your research `:)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use the function [mb_strpos](http://php.net/mb_strpos). It finds the position of first occurrence of string in a string. So if you use in both strings, you can check if the difference between them are 20.

Comment: He can probably just use `strpos`, unless he really needs the multibyte version.

Comment: Once one of the matching words occurs multiple times this is useless, isn't it?

Comment: @kingkero: Maybe, but wasn't a stated requirement.

Comment: @AbraCadaver You are right, but with the obvious regex solution at hand, I don't see any advantage to one like this

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with regex ([explain](http://regex101.com/r/hV3eI2)):

```
$str = 'These people came from some area in France';
$match1 = 'from';
$match2 = 'France';

$is = (bool)preg_match('/\b' . preg_quote($match1) . '\b.{1,20}\b' . preg_quote($match2) . '\b/i', $str);
var_dump($is); # $is variable will be TRUE if there is a match
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/68212)**.

Comment: Is there a specific reasion to use `\b$match1\b` but `$match2\b` (no `\b` at beginning)?

Comment: Haven't seen the use of `\b` before, so I got curious :)

Comment: @kingkero: `\b` is word boundary, which is identical to `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`.

Answer (score 0):

Was already typing it, so I post it :-)

```
if(abs(strpos($str, $match1) - strpos($str, $match2)) <= 20) {
    //within 20
}
```

Use `abs()` if the order of appearance doesn't matter.

Comment: What if one of the searched for words occurs multiple times?